# How to natively turn off internal microphone(mic)?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, webcam, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time. When I went into the sound settings I saw that my laptop's mic is recording:

[image: Laptop's mic is recording]

I've always had my mic and webcam turned off even in Windows for privacy reasons.

However, I was unable to find any option to disable either of them. When I googled it; I was shown some third party softwares to do that. I want to disable them natively either from settings or the terminal.

I'm new to Ubuntu. Any other suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: "Recording" means that the sound picked up by the microphone is being saved to a file somewhere, and can be replayed later. That's not what your information shows. Your information shows that the microphone is merely "On" (for testing, because *you opened that control panel!*), not that anything is being recorded. The difference may seem minor to you, but it's important to ask the right question if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### To disable webcam

You need to blacklist `uvcvideo`.

To do this **temporarily**, open the terminal and execute the following:

```bsh
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

Note that after system restart, the webcam will be enabled again.

To make sure the webcam is always disabled, again open the terminal, and open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` in your favourite text editor, with SU privileges. For example,

```bsh
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf &
```

At the end of the file, append the following lines:

```
# Disable webcam
blacklist uvcvideo
```

Save the file and reboot your system.

Now, say you want to enable your webcam temporarily, but want to keep it disabled by default. In that case, just execute

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

This will bring back the webcam, and the next time you reboot, it will be disabled automatically. If you want to disable it immediately after you use it (which is what I do), then again execute `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`, and it will be disabled, and remain so.

#### To disable microphone

First, you need to find the sound module in your device. To find them, execute the following in the terminal:

```
cat /proc/asound/modules
```

In my laptop, for instance, this returns:

```
0 snd_hda_intel
```

Now you can just go ahead and disable this permanently or temporarily by following what I stated above, just replacing `uvcvideo` with the output you get above (in my case, that would be `snd_hda_intel`).

To permanently disable it between reboots, you can add an entry in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, or use `modprobe` as necessary.

Comment: It would be good to mention that the sound will not work when disabling the microphone with modprobe. I added an answer with more details about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a native tool, but as a beginner a simple GUI tool may be easier:

- install `pavucontrol` via terminal (e.g. `snap install pavucontrol` or `sudo apt install pavucontrol`)
- launch the tool via terminal or via launcher `PulseAudio Volume Control`
- Go to the "Configuration" tab (you might need to resize the window to see it)
- Disable the microphone by switching it to `Off`

This also worked for me after plugging in the webcam again (it's still switched off).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turning the slider all the way to left fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.
If you want to keep the sound, you can just mute the microphone in pavucontrol (or pavucontrol-qt) and select "Analog Stereo Output" instead of "Analog Stereo Duplex".

Disabling the microphone with modprobe may be better since it requires root privileges so a software could not enable the microphone if it is not run as root.
Usually, you can do it the command `sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel` or add "blacklist snd_hda_intel" in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf to keep the blacklist after reboot like mentioned in the answer of Wrichik Basu.
You can try `sudo modprobe -rf snd_hda_intel` if is not working like mentioned on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=821796.

However, the sound will not work anymore so a solution could be to disable the microphone with modprobe only when you don't need sound.
When you need sound, you can enable the sound card and microphone again with the command `sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel`.

But you may get an error `modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel is in use.`.
To solve the issue, I had to kill pulseaudio. You can try with the command `killall pulseaudio` or `killall -9 pulseaudio` if it is not working. Otherwise you can try the same commands by adding sudo before (you may have to wait or try several times until it works).
If you want the sound again, you can restart pulseaudio with the parameters that can be found with the command `ps -ef` before killing it (in my case it was `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal`).